# Why can't I create view table in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have query like this:

```
SELECT 
       generatedTime AS generatedTime,
       tempTable AS tempTable,
       CASE
           WHEN ((generatedTime < maxPelamarmhsdoktor) or (generatedTime < maxAkdmstmayor)
                    or (generatedTime < maxIpbmstdepartemen) or (generatedTime < maxIpbmstfakultas)
                        or (generatedTime < maxIpbrefjeniskelamin) or (generatedTime < maxJenisinstansi)
                            or (generatedTime < maxJenisinstitusi)) THEN
               'Yes'
           ELSE
               'No'
       END AS NeedsToUpdateorNot
FROM generatedtime
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxPelamarmhsdoktor
       FROM pelamarmhsdoktor

     ) AS maxPelamarmhsdoktorFinder
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxAkdmstmayor
       FROM akdmst_mayor

     ) AS maxAkdmstmayorFinder
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxIpbmstdepartemen
       FROM ipbmst_departemen

     ) AS maxIpbmstdepartemenFinder
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxIpbmstfakultas
       FROM ipbmst_fakultas

     ) AS maxIpbmstfakultasFinder
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxIpbrefjeniskelamin
       FROM ipbref_jeniskelamin

     ) AS maxIpbrefjeniskelaminFinder
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxJenisinstansi
       FROM jenisinstansi

     ) AS maxJenisinstansiFinder
JOIN ( SELECT 
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxJenisinstitusi
       FROM jenisinstitusi

     ) AS maxJenisinstitusiFinder
```

Then I want to make that query to be a view table. So I added

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `updateforpelamarmagisterrinci`  AS
```

at the beginning.

But When I tried to create view, the error comes, and the error message is like this

```
#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

What may I do to solve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is clear.  MySQL does not allow views with subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?. See `Before MySQL 5.7.7, subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.`, [C.5 Restrictions on Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html).

Comment: I use `MySQL 10.1.21-MariaDB` but the subqueries still cannot be used @wchiquito

Comment: `The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.`. See [CREATE VIEW](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-view/).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using MariaDB 10.1, you might want to consider upgrading to [MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-102). The limitation on using subqueries in views [was removed in 10.2.1](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-3944). As of now (May 13th, 2017), the latest available 10.2 version is [10.2.5-rc](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.2.5).

The next 10.2.6 is going to be GA (a.k.a. stable release), it is coming soon. Meanwhile, you will have time to test whether 10.2 functionality works well for you, that's what RC is for.

*Note: If you decide to try out the upgrade, it's highly recommended to create a backup of your database before doing so. In case you don't like the version on whatever reason and want to downgrade, using the backup might save you the effort.*

Answer (score 1):

As per MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html), you can't have sub queries in `FROM` clause while creating a `VIEW`, hence the error. However, in your case, you can change the query and try selecting those values in `SELECT` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT 
       (SELECT MAX( last_update ) FROM pelamarmhsdoktor) AS maxPelamarmhsdoktorFinder,
       (SELECT MAX( last_update ) FROM akdmst_mayor) AS maxAkdmstmayorFinder,
       (SELECT MAX( last_update ) FROM ipbmst_departemen) AS maxIpbmstdepartemenFinder,
       (SELECT MAX( last_update ) FROM ipbmst_fakultas) AS maxIpbmstfakultasFinder,
       (SELECT MAX( last_update ) FROM ipbref_jeniskelamin) AS maxJeniskelamin,
       generatedTime AS generatedTime,
       tempTable AS tempTable,
       CASE
           WHEN ((generatedTime < maxPelamarmhsdoktor) or (generatedTime < maxAkdmstmayor)
                    or (generatedTime < maxIpbmstdepartemen) or (generatedTime < maxIpbmstfakultas)
                        or (generatedTime < maxIpbrefjeniskelamin) or (generatedTime < maxJenisinstansi)
                            or (generatedTime < maxJenisinstitusi)) THEN
               'Yes'
           ELSE
               'No'
       END AS NeedsToUpdateorNot
FROM generatedtime;
```

Comment: I tried that query. But that query doesn't work. It gives me some errors

Comment: Underlying error is `unknown column maxPelamarmhsdoktor`, maybe that column doesn't exist?

Comment: `maxPelamarmhsdoktor` is an alias. I have aliased it at the beginning.

Comment: I have changed the ordering of columns in the answer. However, you need to change the `CASE` statement and make sure the aliases you are using are selected in `SELECT` queries above

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, well structured, but some work:

1. Create a view for each table where you need time columns. All you do in this view is select the `MAX(last_update)`.
2. Create a view where you `UNION` all the views created in step 1 and select the `MAX(last_update)` again, I call the view `vAll` for simplicity.
3. Now you can easily create the view you want to:

   ```
   SELECT
      generatedTime AS generatedTime,
      tempTable AS tempTable,
      CASE WHEN generated_time < last_update THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS NeedsToUpdateorNot
   FROM generatedtime, vAll;
   ```

Alternatively try to do all in the select clause:

```
SELECT
   generatedTime AS generatedTime,
   tempTable AS tempTable,
   CASE WHEN generated_time < (
      SELECT MAX(last_update) AS last_update FROM (
          (SELECT MAX(last_update) AS last_update FROM a) UNION
          (SELECT MAX(last_update) AS last_update FROM b) UNION
          (SELECT MAX(last_update) AS last_update FROM c) UNION
          ...
      )
   ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS NeedsToUpdateorNot
FROM generatedtime;
```

Comment: There will be so many tables if I make table views like that, because I have so many tables to join. Is there any other way to solve the subquery?

Comment: @r34627673 check alternative.

Comment: Added corrections, you need to take two times the max (not min) and then you can get rid of all the ors. @r34627673

Comment: Thankyou maraca ;) may you have a nice day. GBU

Answer (score 0):

Move your sub query to view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_max_pelamarmhsdoktor AS 
    SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxPelamarmhsdoktor FROM pelamarmhsdoktor
...

...
```

your query become:

```
SELECT 
       generatedTime AS generatedTime,
       tempTable AS tempTable,
       CASE
           WHEN ((generatedTime < maxPelamarmhsdoktor) or (generatedTime < maxAkdmstmayor)
                    or (generatedTime < maxIpbmstdepartemen) or (generatedTime < maxIpbmstfakultas)
                        or (generatedTime < maxIpbrefjeniskelamin) or (generatedTime < maxJenisinstansi)
                            or (generatedTime < maxJenisinstitusi)) THEN
               'Yes'
           ELSE
               'No'
       END AS NeedsToUpdateorNot
FROM generatedtime
JOIN v_max_pelamarmhsdoktor AS maxPelamarmhsdoktorFinder
...

...
```